# decomposition of a permutation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Claim:

if G is a finite group with $|G|=n$ and $g\in G$ of order $d$ then $\phi(g)$ is the product of $n/d$ disjoint cycles of length $d$.

Notation:

$\phi(g)$ is the effective action of G on itself: $\phi: G \Rightarrow S_{|G|}$

What I did:

Let $(x_i)_{i\in \{1,...,n/d\}} = Stab_G(g)$.

I tried to build the cycles as follow:
$c_i(x)=
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 & x\ if\ x \in Stab_G(x_i)\\ 
 & \phi(g)(x) \ otherwise 
\end{matrix}\right.
$

Is it a good way to go?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If $g \neq 1$, then $g$ does not have any fix point. Therefore in the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\phi(g)$, there is no cycle of length $1$, and every letter appears exactly once. Hence it suffices to show that every cycle has length $d$, or equivalently every orbit has size $d$. Indeed, for any $a \in G$, the orbit of $a$ is $\{a,ga,g^2a,\ldots,g^{d-1}a\}$.

$\phi(g)$ can be written out explicitly. Let $\mathcal{O}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{O}_{n/d}$ be all orbits, pick $a_i \in \mathcal{O}_i$, then
$\phi(g)=\prod_{i=1}^{n/d} (a_i \; ga_i \; \cdots \; g^{d-1}a_i)$.